# does UIL support Google webp format

Tags: webp

Since Android 4.0 below doesn't support Google webp format, what happened if I pass webp format as the uri parameter under Android 4.0 below? Will UIL decode webp format to bitmap automatically, or I have to implement the decoding method myself? If so, which class should I implement or which method should I override?

Thanks.